# More heaps found in each dump, where do they come from?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, native, windbg

I am investigating a native memory leak through WinDbg.

With consecutive dumps, `!heap -s` returns more heaps every dump. Number of heaps returned in the first dump: 1170, second dump: 1208.

There are three sizes of heaps that are returning a lot:

```
0:000> !heap -stat -h 2ba60000
heap @ 2ba60000
group-by: TOTSIZE max-display: 20

size     #blocks     total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)
1ffa 1 - 1ffa  (35.44)
1000 1 - 1000  (17.73)
a52 1 - a52  (11.44)
82a 1 - 82a  (9.05)
714 1 - 714  (7.84)
64c 1 - 64c  (6.98)
```

Most blocks refer to the same callstack:

```
777a5887 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap
73f9f1de sqlsrv32!SQLAllocateMemory
73fc0370 sqlsrv32!SQLAllocConnect
73fc025d sqlsrv32!SQLAllocHandle
74c6a146 odbc32!GetInfoForConnection
74c6969d odbc32!SQLInternalDriverConnectW
74c6bc24 odbc32!SQLDriverConnectW
74c63141 odbc32!SQLDriverConnect
```

When will a new heap will be created, and how you would dive deeper into this to find the root cause?

Comment: I'd guess it's just leaking a SQL connection object; the additional heaps are maybe not relevant as they're internal to the odbc library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to do live debugging, you can try to set a break:

```
bp ntdll!RtlCreateHeap "kc;gc"
```

will display the call stack and continue. Maybe you see the culprit.
Do also the same with ntdll!RtlDebugCreateHeap

Comment: Is there any chance you know the opposite of the createHeap function? I See that SQL is creating heaps, but it would be handy to see if he also deletes the heap. (Quite new into memleak research)

Comment: I don't know the opposite , you can hunt yourself by using x kernel32!HeapDestroy
or similar.
 Or make a test program and step into https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366700(v=vs.85).aspx